# How to plot two subsets of a value column based on a factor column best in a scatter plot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am wondering what's the simplest way to plot two subsets of a value column against each other (e.g. scatter plot with ggplot)?
Example `datframe` =

```
Intensity Factor Order
1 red 1
2 red 2
3 red 3
1 green 1
3 green 2
5 green 3
```

Corresponding values are defined by the Order column. The goal would be to now plot corresponding red vs. green intensity values. Is there a simple way to do this in ggplot besides subsetting the dataframe into two beforehand?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Do you want the max or min of each 'Factor

Comment: Also, does the first "red" value correspond to the first "green" value ? How to you match red versus green ?

Comment: Good points, forgot to mention. Yes, the order is the same and defined by a third column. Added now in question. I would like to have a scatter xy plot (red vs green).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can reshape to 'wide' format and then do the plot with `geom_point`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(rn = rowid(Factor)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = Factor, values_from = Intensity) %>% 
    select(-rn) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = red, y = green)) + 
          geom_point()
```

-output
[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Intensity = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 5L), Factor = c("red", 
"red", "red", "green", "green", "green")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks, looks pretty simple to me! Could you explain why you need to have create a row number column?

Comment: @gdeniz it is just `pivot_wider` doesn't understand which value become to which row, so there needs to be sequence by the 'Factor' to assist it